# Img tag does not works in react js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm making a web with react-js in Git Hub. I'm using MUI to decorate my web, but there aren't any tags to get the image to the web in MUI, so I get the `<img/>` tag. This is my Home.js file:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Box, Button, TextField, Card, Typography} from '@mui/material'
import products from '../images/products'
import logo from '../images/logo.png'

const Home = () => {
    return (
        <Box>
            <Box sx={{display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "row",
            height: "100px",
            border: '3px solid DodgerBlue',
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "right"
            }}>
                <Box sx={{display: "flex", flexDirection: 'row', width: "50%", justifyContent: "center"}}>
                    <img src={logo} />
                </Box>
                <TextField label='Nhập tên thật'  variant='outlined' required />
                <TextField label='Nhập số điện thoại'  variant='outlined' required/>
                <TextField label='Nhập địa chỉ'  variant='outlined' required/>
                <Button variant='contained' size='large' sx={{height: "50px", m: "25px"}}>Đăng kí</Button>
            </Box>
            <Box sx={{display: "flex", flexDirection: "row"}}>
                {products.map((item, index) => <Card key={index} sx={{alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center", border: "1.5px dashed black", margin: 5, width: 200}} >
                    <Box sx={{display: "flex", flexDirection: 'row', width: "100%", height: "100px"}}>
                        <img src={item.img} />
                    </Box>
                    <Typography variant="h5">{item.name}</Typography>
                    <Typography variant="h6">{item.price}k/hộp</Typography>
                    <TextField variant="outlined" type="number" label="Số hộp"></TextField>
                    <Button variant='contained'>Thêm vào giỏ</Button>
                </Card>)}
            </Box>
        </Box>
)}
export default Home
```

My product.js:

```
const products = [
    {
    id:0,
    name:"Đậu phộng tỏi ớt nhỏ (250g)",
    price: 35,
    img: "img1.png"
},
{
    id:1,
    name:"Đậu phộng tỏi ớt lớn (500g)",
    price: 70,
    img: "img2.png"
},
{
    id:2,
    name:"Bột ngũ cốc nhỏ (500g)",
    price: 35,
    img: "img3.png"
},
{
    id:3,
    name:"Bột ngũ cốc lớn (1kg)",
    price: 70,
    img: "img4.png"
}]
export default products
```

The folder structure:

- src
- - images
- - - (5 images)
- - - product.js
- - views
- - - Home.js

The web not shows my item.img. It shows a file icon.
Please help me to do it.

Comment: The file icon you describe just makes me think that the `src` for your image does not exist or cannot be found. What is the `src` of that `<img />` tag in your browsers output and when you follow that link, is there something there?

Comment: If your image is a relative URL and you're running your project locally then you should be able to see your image in the browser with an url that looks like `http://localhost:8000/path/to/my/image.png`. Replace the port with the port you're using and the path with whatever is stored in `item.img`.

Comment: That is irrelevant, parcel does not care about the files URLs are pointing too (it would be very inefficient to parse them and include them in a bundle as it prevents them from being cached and loads of other things). Please verify that your image is working first. We still don't know what `item.img` returns so we can't help you until you give us something to work with. Also, Parcel doesn't care whether your file is a valid file either - if the image file exists with broken data, the result would be the same: a broken image with a file icon.

Comment: Sorry for my comment. @somethinghere

Comment: You don't have to say sorry! It's okay, I was just pointing out that Parcel doesn't really solve the issue I already pointed out. By what you describe, it looks as if the image just isn't found. Parcel doesn't really care about that stuff, it cares about your code, not links your code references. (If you would host images on a CDN, parcel wouldn't be able to process them but it throwing an error would be... impossible to build with in that case)

Comment: So that confirms it: your images are not found. I looked in your products.js file, and it contains objects like `{ img: 'somename.jpg' }`. When react is done rendering, your final image code would be `<img src="somename.jpg" />` which means your image needs to be right next to the current output page. You might want to try `/images/somename.jpg` instead of just the image, because _how is the browser supposed to know where the file is located_? It can't just search your servers filesystem until it finds a match. You will have to find a way to hook up your image path correctly.

Comment: It's a little hard to help you with the exact implementation because it depends on so many factors: does parcel copy the image to your dist? If so, what is the path? What path is used when rendering the page (is it `/home/` or `/index.html`? Are your image URLs relative (they currently are) and should they be absolute (starting with the `/` root slash)? Because it matters depending on from where you want to load the image. There are too many factors at play here to really help, but this is why.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said, the image is not found. This is because the images are relative to the page that is loading them. If the page loading them is `/views/home` (which I'm still not sure is, but let's go with that), simply doing this:

```
<img src={item.img} />
```

*won't work*, because the output would just be `<img src="image.jpg" />`, which would mean the image should be right next to the loaded page in `views/home`. React, nor parcel, nor anything else really, knows what you want to achieve. Even `products.js` does not actually know about where the images are, even if they are accidentally next to it.

You need to point to your images folder in more absolute terms, like from the root. Since you know that, in the end, all your images will be in `/images/`, you can just add that to your url:

```
<img src={`/images/${item.img}`} />
```

If parcel copies over your images folder, this should work. But you need to tell parcel to do that, otherwise you will have no images inside your `dist` folder that parcel creates and then runs a local server from, which would again result in missing images.

I'll be honest, I think Parcel + React is maybe too many points of failure if you are unfamiliar with the structure of the web or websites. You are better off learning the fundamentals like HTML, CSS and JS and simple file and folder structures that are used before trying to build something in larger libraries on top, because it makes it hard to debug or even reason or ask questions about.

I'm pretty sure parcel will not understand that React composed image URLs are resources it should copy and give unique hashes etc. It's been a while since I used it, but I just don't see how it can do that without actually fully building your page just to know what images will be used.

I hope this helps point you in the right direction, but it is still very hard to resolve your issue as there are so many factors at play here.